# What is the difference between ROLE and PRIVILEGE for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, permissions, role

Is `role` a collection of certain `privilege`s?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, a role is a collection of system and/or object privileges and/or other roles.  It simplifies privilege management by allowing you to manage bundles of privileges.

Comment: @ScottCher Can roles be assigned to roles?

Comment: Yes.  You can have roles granted to other roles.